# Modifying managed objects obtained from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, core-data

I have a simply core data model which has two entities, a Person and a Photo. Person has a one-to-many relationship with Photos. Everything works fine, and when I access the photoList property on Person I get an NSSet with all the photos for that person.

My question is, how can I modify the managed objects in that set and the commit the results back to the core data backstore? At the moment, if I modify one of the Photo managed objects in the set they don't get saved.

The code looks something like this:

```
Person *myPerson = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[photosController setPhotos:[[myPerson photoList] allObjects]];
```

Where the set that the photosController gets is perfectly readable, but modifying its content does not update the backend store.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to managed objects are only retained in memory until you [save the managed object context](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-BAJCEDBI) of the objects. Once that's done, the changes will be committed to the persistent store.